# Automatically produce aliases for all columns in SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, excel, notepad++

I'm using Microsoft Query to pull data from MS SQL Server to Excel. Many of my tables have the same column names, for example:

```
[task].[active]
[user].[active]

[task].[name]
[user].[name]
```

When I pivot in Excel, only the column names are shown. A pivot filter might have multiple fields called "active" which is very confusing.

I'd like to alias every column with the table name it's from, so that in the filter it would say "task_active" and "user_active". My Excel SELECT statement would be:

```
SELECT active AS task_active, name AS task_name FROM task...
```

Is there a quick way to prepend the table name to an alias using a formatting tool? I have Apex SQL Refactor, and Notepad++ but I haven't found a way to do this without having to manually type all of the column names again.

Comment: No, there is not.  You can construct the query pretty easily though by using the information_schema tables, loading the data in Excel, and then constructing the query.

Comment: Perhaps a view would be helpful for this?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you, this is the easiest method. I pulled the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table, used Excel CONCAT() to construct the aliases and copied them out to Notepad++ to construct my query.

Can you please add your comment as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

If you populate resultset to datatable then datatable to excel then it will automatically change duplicate column name to col1,col2 etc.

This is not your requirement.you want it to be specific.

`Method 1` . Create temp table with desire column name

Insert the result in #temp table

Return #temp table result set

`Method 2` : Use dynamic query.

Wht your real query look like ?